# What's a good Maven project structure when developing in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, code-organization

I am new with the Maven. I have two projects. I want this kind of tree:

project1
 
--pom.xml

project2
 
--pom.xml

pom.xml

which means I performed aggregation and inheritance. By doing like this and importing two projects in eclipse, the second project can't see junit dependency which is specified in the outer - common pom.xml.
The problem with the first project is that instead of having packages i see only folders.

Comment: "instead of having packages i see only folders" did you try [right click project] --> [maven] --> [update project configuration] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Package Explorer in Eclipse in order to see packages instead folders.
Also for this kind of inheritance try to add both projects in one parent project and import this one into Eclipse. In both .pom files of projects you must specify their parent project

Answer (score 0):

As MykoB has said, ensure the *common* `pom.xml` has `project1` and `project2` defined as `modules`.  In each of the child project, specify the *common* `pom.xml` as `parent`.

Choose the folder containing the parent `pom.xml` when importing the project in Eclipse and you should have the parent and both the child modules imported correctly.

This assumes you have the latest Eclipse Indigo with m2e plugin.

Answer (score 0):

What you've built is the correct default Maven module structure, but Eclipse likes to have all its projects at the same level. That is, your root pom.xml which contains the module entries should be in a folder of its own, like so:

```
WorkspaceFolder
\_project1 
   \_pom.xml 
\_project2 
   \_pom.xml
\_Builder 
   \_pom.xml
\_Parent
   \_pom.xml
```

The Builder pom.xml has module entries that look like `<module>../project1</module>`. That's your aggregation part. Additionally, if you want to have a parent pom for inheritance (which is not necessarily related to having a pom with modules), you'll have to add the Parent entry to project1, project2 and Builder's pom.xml, and you'll need to have a `<relativePath>../Parent</relativePath>`.

Note that all relative paths come from the problem that you're adapting your subfolder structure to what eclipse likes.